# How to display front end data from TMDB using api

Tags: php, html, laravel, api

I am using laravel 6 for a college project in which I need to display information from TMDB for a media review site in which I am creating. I am quite new to laravel so I am struggling with getting this working. I have made an account on tmdb and I have acquired a key to use the api. So far I am able to call the data in the google chrome console using this code my lecturer gave me,

```
<script>
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/111?api_key=...&language=en-US
var api_key = '...';
var baseUrl = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/';

fetch(baseUrl+'movie/111?api_key='+api_key+'&language=en+US')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(function(data){
  console.log("all data");
  console.log(data);
});
</script>
```

This displays the movie with the id 111 in the console. I'm wondering how I can display this information through HTML and PHP in laravel. I already have the code in which I can create my own movies in my own attached database. For this project however, I need to display information from the online database on the front end. Sorry if this is not explained in proper detail or if I left parts out, I am very new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You should add http client library to you Laravel project, like 'guzzle' for example.

Here is an article that should explain this in detail: [laravel-6-guzzle-http-client-exampleexample](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-6-guzzle-http-client-exampleexample.html)

Guzzle documentation: [guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/)

Then you can do something like this:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request(
    'GET',
    'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/111',
    [
        'query' => [
            'api_key' => 'YOUR_API_KEY',
            'language' => 'en-US'
        ]
    ]
);

$body = $response->getBody();
$data = json_decode($body);

print_r($data);
```

P.S.
You probably shouldn't post api keys in your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the heads up, i'll definitely look into this. Thank you !